# How to use AFRAME.TWEEN

Tags: aframe

I found a response from Diego Marcos "FYI, You don't have to import TWEEN.js again. You can access the version bundled with A-Frame via AFRAME.TWEEN: new AFRAME.TWEEN.Tween(animation)" but I can not do it works with frame 0.9.0 version.

Answer (score 0):

A-Frame moved away from TWEEN and it now uses [anime.js](https://animejs.com/). It’s exposed on AFRAME.ANIME